# Get index of specific value in requested JSON

Tags: jquery, json

How do I get the JSON index of a specific value in my structure here? Lets say I want to know the index of `"year": 2080` which would equal to index 1

```
{"elements":[
    {
        "year": 1971,
    },
    {
        "year": 2080,
    },
    {
        "year": 3060,
    }
]}
```

Im requesting as so:

```
var jsonUrl = "myurl.json";
$.getJSON( jsonUrl, {
    format: "json"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
      //traverse through JSON
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```
var idx = data.elements.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el.year === 2080;
});
```

Note that this is an ES6+ method, so it won't be available by default in older browsers. It is, however, trivial to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).

Alternatively, you can just kick it old-school:

```
var idx = -1;

for (var i = 0, len = data.elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (data.elements[i].year === 2080) {
        idx = i;
        break;
    }
}
```